# How can a TikZ node be placed along an edge specified with "to path"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw an `edge` between two TikZ nodes specified using the `to path` construct and place a node (a label) along the edge. Placing `node[options] {text}` after the `edge` does not seem to work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, circle, radius=1] (q0) at (0,0) {};
  \node[draw, circle, radius=1] (q1) at (2,0) {};
  \draw (q0) edge[to path={.. controls (1,1) .. (\tikztotarget)}, ->] node[above] {x} (q1)
             edge[->, bend right=15] node[below] {y} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second edge gets labeled by "y" and I can control its position using the `pos` option to the node. The first edge has no label at all.

How can I label the first edge in a similar fashion to the second? In particular, I'd like to avoid having to add a new `\draw`, `\path`, `\node` or similar since I'm constructing my diagrams programmatically from some tables of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the option to path will have "grater priority" the way it is set than the node command (that is ignored)... This, happens because of the (\tikztoterget) that is there (and being replaced later) before the command for the node

You could try this way:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, circle, radius=1] (q0) at (0,0) {};
  \node[draw, circle, radius=1] (q1) at (2,0) {};
  \draw (q0) edge[to path={.. controls (1,1) ..node[above] {x} (\tikztotarget)}, ->]  (q1)
             edge[->, bend right=15] node[below] {y} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

Comment: Welcome... The comments above is the way I understand the procedure from the code and the results... So, don't pay more attention that needed...  :P